# Error with inline and Xcode 4.2.1

Tags: xcode, r, osx-lion, inline, rcpp

I'm trying to get the [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/inline/index.html) package working on my macbook.  The following block of code (from the cxxfunction examples) fails:

```
library(inline)
fx <- cxxfunction( signature(x = "integer", y = "numeric" ) , '
    return ScalarReal( INTEGER(x)[0] * REAL(y)[0] ) ;
' )
fx( 2L, 5 )
```

With this error:

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! make: g++-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [file141b5882.o] Error 1
```

This is strange, because g++ is available:

```
g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.1~22/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.1~22/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)

ls /usr/bin | grep gcc
gcc
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2
llvm-gcc
llvm-gcc-4.2
```

I've running Xcode 4.2.1, R 2.14.0, on Mac OS 10.7.2.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

After doing some research, it turns out this is an easy problem to fix:

```
sudo ln -sn /usr/bin/g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.2
sudo ln -sn /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Inline and Rcpp seem to be working correctly now.

Comment: "After doing some research..." does that mean we should down-vote your question for lack of research effort? ;-)

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: Just because this is the first solution I could find doesn't mean it is the correct one!

Comment: thanks for asking and answering and linking from elsewhere to this solution.  Fixed for me as well :)