# g++-4.2: No such file or directory mac os 10.8

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, makefile, g++

I am getting an error when I run the command make on mac os 10.8.5.

error :

```
>make sample
g++-4.2   -O3  -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -I/usr/include -D_x64 -D_OSX -Wall -I../../inc-pc -D_REENTRANT  Stream.cpp -o Stream -lpthread -lz -Bdynamic -lm -lc -L../../bin-pc/x64 -lPvAPI
make: g++-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [sample] Error 1
```

But when I run these command I get like this:

```
     which gcc
        /usr/bin/gcc

     which g++
       /usr/bin/g++
ls -l `which g++`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  3 13 Mar 00:48 /usr/bin/g++ -> gcc
```

What is the problem? Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same problem. I symlinked /usr/bin/g++ to /usr/bin/g++-4.2 and it resolved my issues.

Comment: This is the correct answer, [per here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368834/error-with-inline-and-xcode-4-2-1)

Answer (score 0):

Your makefile calls `g++-4.2` instead of `g++` to  compile. `g++-42` is either not present on your system or is not available on the path.

You can try fixing your makefile: Search for `g++-4.2` in the makefile and replace the string with `g++`